# nmap shows me that one service is "open|filtered" while locally it's "open", how to open?

Tags: firewall, services

I have a Quake 3 server. And it's launched successfully.

The problem is that no one can connect to that server.

I am running: `nmap -sU -p 27960 hostname` and it's showing me that it's state `open|filtered`

if I am running that command right from the server it is `open`.

Also, I am making sure that it's binding to the right `iface`

I checked the **iptables** rules and couldn't find any filters related to it. Furthermore, I tried to open the port explicitly via `iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27960 -j ACCEPT`

but this didn't help.

What it could be?

I called to ISP support center and they said they are not filtering anything.

Comment: Whether the iface in which you are hosting the server is having public or private IP ?

Comment: @pradeepchhetri it has only one, public IP

Comment: If you are using linux machine, can you try connecting using `nc <ipaddress> 27960` from some other machine.

Comment: Which Linux Distro you are using ?

Comment: I run that comment from my laptop to that server. it's just stuck. nothing is shown. The distro is Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Actually getting stuck means the port is listening and it is getting connected. If you gave the same command with some non-open port, it will just end and show prompt.

Comment: but it's stuck on other ports too which are supposed to be closed

Comment: Hey can you try the steps which I mentioned.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Getting different nmap results from local machine and remote machines means there is some kind of firewall(whether running locally or some remote machine) which is blocking. According to the nmap documentation,

```
open|filtered

Nmap places ports in this state when it is unable to determine whether  
a port is open or filtered. This occurs for scan types in which open
ports give no response. The lack of response could also mean that a 
packet filter dropped the probe or any response it elicited. So Nmap 
does not know for sure whether the port is open or being filtered. The
UDP, IP protocol, FIN, NULL, and Xmas scans classify ports this way.
```

I would recommend you to try out following tools to find out whether exactly the problem exists:

1. To capture the UDP packets destined to `port 27960` using `tcpdump` and . Check whether the packets are reaching your machine or not.

Run the following command to capture the udp packets destined to port 27960 in a file `tcpdump.out`

```
$ sudo tcpdump -A 'udp and port 27960' -w tcpdump.out`
```

Try connecting from other machine to port using `netcat`

```
$ nc <server-ip-address> -u 27960
```

Now stop the dump and check whether any packet got captured in the tcpdump.out or not using wireshark.

```
$ wireshark tcpdump.out
```

If no packet got captured, this means some intermediate device(firewall) is preventing the communication. Else, if captured check the reply which the server is giving in return of the request. If it is any kind of ICMP reply with some error code, it means there is some local firewall which is blocking.

Comment: This is cool! I see that packets are really coming. But client can't connect and no error msgs in the client side for some reasons. I also couldn't find any ICMP packets. But I think the question is actually answered. Other things are not quite related to my issue.

Comment: There is some problem, which we are still not able to figure out.

Comment: I am making some local tests. Will keep updated here

Comment: @casey_miller: Awesome !! That would be really helpful.

Comment: This is still strange. I tried another server but before testing on a remote server I tested on the LAN just to make sure client and the server are fine. So it worked! But after I moved the q3 server to the remote server and launched - no luck. "Awaiting connection ...<nn>"

Comment: Wireshark showing that the packets are "malformed" could this mean that the packets are mangled and corrupted on the way?

Comment: Alright, just to close the gestalt. The problem was in my local firewall.

Comment: @casey_miller: Can you explain me what kind of problem was there in local firewall ?

Comment: I had CSF firewall which was blocking those packets